# passing and reading data from firebase firestore

Tags: javascript, html, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

the error:

> autofillContentScript.bundle.js:23 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError:
> Cannot read properties of null (reading 'includes')
> at autofillContentScript.bundle.js:23:256161
> at p (autofillContentScript.bundle.js:23:4111)
> at Generator._invoke (autofillContentScript.bundle.js:23:3899)
> at Generator.next (autofillContentScript.bundle.js:23:4540)
> at e (autofillContentScript.bundle.js:23:166490)
> at s (autofillContentScript.bundle.js:23:166693)
> at autofillContentScript.bundle.js:23:166752
> at new Promise ()
> at autofillContentScript.bundle.js:23:166633
> at go (autofillContentScript.bundle.js:23:259494)

I tried to fix this problem by clearing cache but it didnt worked...

my code:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", event => {
    const app = firebase.app();
    
    const db = firebase.firestore();

    const myVid = db.collection('videos').doc('conditions');

    myVid.onSnapshot(doc => {

        const data = doc.data();
        console.log(data.subject)
        console.log(data.page)
    })
});

function update(e){
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    const myVid = db.collection('videos').doc('conditions');
    myVid.update({
        subject: e.target.value
    })
}

function val(e) {
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    const myVid = db.collection('videos').doc('conditions');
    myVid.update({
        page: e.target.value
    })
}
```

I would tell you if I knew where the problem is...
But I really have no clue about what this error even means and what is causin it.

someone can help me?
how can I fix this problem?

Comment: The code you shared doesn't seem to be causing the problem. If you comment all of it out and re-run, what happens? What imports are you using?

Comment: I fixed the problem.
seems that one of google's extantions was causing it